# How to get a graph of dependencies of Haskell project

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a several executable targets in the project, like:

```
...
app/
other_app/
src/
package.yaml
stack.yaml
...
```

so, I have obviously different .hs files in `app/`, `other_app/`, `src/`. If I build it with `stack` tool then it build `app`s and `other_app`s executables from their dependencies, ie, if some .hs file changed in `src/` - the result executable will be rebuild. Otherwise - no. `stack` knows a graph of dependencies like GNU make does it. How to list/print this graph? For example, for C I have [makedepend tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend) which is able to extract dependencies recursively from .c files. Is it possible to be done for Haskell files? With `stack` tool itself? Maybe with a `cabal` tool? I tried, for example, `v2-freeze` of the cabal tool, but it is not related to the problem.

UPDATE:

package.yaml looks like:

```yaml
.............
executables:
  app1-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app1
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - app1

  app2-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app2
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - app1
............
```

and now I want to list recursively dependencies (in Makefile-style, not dependencies on packages, like `stack dot` does it!), for instance for app2's Main.hs, something like:

- src/Component1/Types.hs
- src/Component1/Utils.hs
- src/CoolLibrary/CoolUtility.hs
  ...

Comment: Try `stack dot`: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/dependency_visualization/

Comment: I am running it in the project folder but the result is just `strict digraph deps {
"myproject" [style=solid];
{rank=max; "myproject"; };
}`

Comment: Which components did you define in the `package.yaml`? Can you paste the relevant parts into the issue description?

Comment: Maybe `graphmod` will do what you want: https://github.com/yav/graphmod/wiki